# Surface plot on top of colour image (x-y plane)

Tags: matlab, bitmap, plot

I guess, I've got an colormap issue with Matlab2013. I plot a 3d surface plot with colormap hot and I would like to have in the same plot an bitmap (8bit colour image) on the x-y plane. Plotting both separately from each other works fine but as soon as I plot them in one figure the first surface plot is only black. I guess it is because the RGB image on the x-y plane uses a different colour map. Is there an option in Matlab to plot two different type of images in the same plot?

```
surf(X,Y,density,'FaceColor','texturemap','Edgecolor','none')
colormap hot
...
%// define the location of the bitmap
xImage = [miX maX; miX maX];              %// The y data for the image corners
yImage = [miY miY; maY maY];              %// The x data for the image corners
zImage = [zDist zDist; zDist zDist];      %// The z data for the image corners  
surf(xImage,yImage,zImage,...             %// Plot the surface
    'CData',RGBImage,...
    'FaceColor','texturemap');
```

Thanks!
Durin

Comment: Can you provide the image as well as the corresponding values in `xImage, yImage` and `zImage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue with the relative scaling of `density` and `zImage`.  I can replicate this by doing the following:

1) Plot a `surf` where the third input is *n x m* which is scaled like some real data (-0.2 to +0.2, for example).  This responds to changes in `colormap` as you'd expect.

2) After `hold on`, plot another `surf` where the third input is *n x m x 3*, like a RGB image, double values scaled between 0 and 1.

This causes the first image to go "dark" (or whatever the lowest color in that particular colormap is).  The issue is that they share their `CLim`, being in the same axis, although the `RGBImage` doesn't, in fact, reference the colormap.

This is "fixable" by scaling/normalising the first plot (your `density` values) to be between 0 and 1 (in this case) - although this quick fix is going to give you issues if you then want to add a colorbar.  Alternatively, first grab the "CLim" from your axis after plotting the first surf:

```
trueC = get(gca,'CLim');
```

Then set it back after you plot the image:

```
set(gca,'CLim',trueC)
```